# Pull object as variable from PHP array (in Drupal 7 module)

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7

Hopefully I'm asking this in a way that makes sense. Couldn't find anything out there that answered this, though I may not have been phrasing my search terms correctly.

In my Drupal 7 custom module I am able to get data out of a Taxonomy array successfully using the following object operator (arrow `->`) syntax

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($taxonomy_tid);
$description = $term->description;
echo $description;
```

How can I make the "description" label itself a variable? The set up would be:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($taxonomy_tid);
$description_name_from_array = 'description';
$description = $term->????;
echo $description;
```

Things that don't work:

- `$term->$description_name_from_array`
- `$term->[$description_name_from_array]`
- `$term->&$description_name_from_array`

Comment: You are going to have to rephrase your question I think. To me it does not make sense what you are trying to do. [taxonomy_term_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7.x) returns a taxonomy object, I am unsure why you are referring to arrays. Are you trying to set a new variable on the taxonomy object itself?

Comment: Maybe if you broaden your question a bit and tell us what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Curly braces** may be required in specific cases, but your 1st try should work for accessing *description*. The correct syntax for accessing a simple variable property from an object is

```
 $obj->$property
```

> Class properties may also be accessed using variable property names.
>   The variable property name will be resolved within the scope from
>   which the call is made. For instance, if you have an expression such
>   as `$foo->$bar`, then the local scope will be examined for `$bar` and its
>   value will be used as the name of the property of `$foo`. This is also
>   true if `$bar` is an array access.

It's safer though to encapsulate the variable with curly braces to clearly delimit the property name :

```
$obj->{$property}
```

It is *required* when :

- accessing values within a property that contains an array : `$obj->${$properties[0]}`
- when the property name is made of multiple parts : `$obj->{$a . $b}`
- when using a constant to access the property : `$obj->{CONSTANT_NAME}`
- or when the property name contains characters that are not otherwise valid

See PHP's [Variable Variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Curly brackets did the trick!


$description = $term->{$description};